# Вопрос по задаче и работе с ф-й scipy.optimize.golden

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Запутался какие аргументы мы берем из функции `golden()`  в первом случае и потом передаем в ф-и `f()`, `g()` ? Уже второй день перебираю варианты и продвинулся, но все же выскакивает ошибка, при попытке вызывать последние ф-и `ff(min_fff)`.

Правильно ли я передаю аргуметы и в нужную функцию?
Буду очень благодарен за помощь 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from scipy.optimize import golden

a = 3
b = 4

def f(x):
     return ((x+a)**2)-b

def g(x):
    return (abs(f(x)))

min_f = (golden(f, brack=(-10, -4), full_output=True)) # получили минимум аргумента ф-и f
min_g = (golden(g, brack=(-10, -4), full_output=True)) # получили минимум аргумента ф-и g

#full_output - если равен True, то функция возвращает кортеж вида (аргумент_минимума, функция_минимума, число итераций)

#print(min_f) 
#print(min_g) 

min_ff=list(min_f) # берем значение аргумента [0] элемент списка и подставляем в ф-ю 
min_gg=list(min_g) # берем значение аргумента [0] элемент списка и подставляем в ф-ю (какю ф-ю, fg или golden?)

min_fff = min_ff[1] 
min_ggg = min_gg[1]

# print (min_fff)
# print (min_ggg)

# print(type(min_fff))
# print(type(min_ggg))

# ---- вызов функций с передачей в них минимумов аргументов функций f g не дал результата

def ff(min_fff):
    print (((min_fff+a)**2)-b)

def gg(min_ggg):
    print(abs(((min_ggg+a)**2)-b))

ff(min_fff)
gg(min_ggg)

# ---- вызову функиции и педедача в них минимума функции т.е из ответа godlen березм [1] элемент

#print (min_fff)
#print (min_ggg)

#print(type(min_fff))


# ------ попытка передать аргументы ф-й для поиска минимума не увенчались успехом

#min1 = (golden(min_fff, brack=(-10, -4), full_output=True)) # получили минимум аргумента ф-и f
#min2 = (golden(min_ggg, brack=(-10, -4), full_output=True)) # получили минимум аргумента ф-и g
#print(min1,min2)

# ------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При использовании параметра `full_output=True` функция `golden()` вернет следующий кортеж:

```
(<значения аргумента функции в точке минимума>, 
 <значение самой функции в точке минимума>,
 <число итераций понадобившихся для нахождения минимума>)
```

Пример:

```
In [100]: arg_f, val_f, iter_f = golden(f, brack=(-10, -4), full_output=True)

In [101]: arg_g, val_g, iter_g = golden(f, brack=(-10, -4), full_output=True)

In [102]: arg_f
Out[102]: -2.9999999946128693

In [103]: val_f
Out[103]: -4.0
```

Т.е. функция `f(x)` имеет минимум в точке `x = -3` и значение функции в этой точке: `f(-3) = -4`

проверим:

```
In [104]: f(arg_f)
Out[104]: -4.0
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь я разобрался после такого полного и с подробностями, примерами ответа! Оказывается все вполне четко и логично)

Comment: @AlexSapsay, всегда рад помочь :)